# Why the plot is not stacked bar in python(pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have metled a data using `pd.melt` function in pandas and pivoted the table keeping the name and year as id. Then I have got the table which I want. But, while ploting the graph, its not proper(means I am not getting what I want). The below is the code which gives the work done so far.

[image]

[image]

I have prefered to do this method since i have other variable with same name and years.(may be some other method exists)

But I want the graph something like, having bars representing 'Estimated Number of Pregnacies' for each state(including all india) over the years as side by side bars.

### How to achieve this?

Comment: Please don't paste images of dataframes in your question -- make your sample data [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) instead.

Comment: I didnt know how to give data. Thats why I have added the image. How to give the data? @cmaher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of what you are doing. Hope this gives you some hint:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
                   'class' : [1,2,1,2,1,2],
                    'vals':[122,1122,3342,4431,4311,1989]})

# use groupby on columns you want to see on x axis
df.groupby(['name','class'])['vals'].sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes..this works well.. What does that `.sum()` does ? I didnt understand that part. @YOLO

Comment: @gloom `.sum()` calculate the sum of vals column for each name and class column. You can read more about here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html